# Google Analytics API PHP -Get Top 5 Pages

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to work out how to get the top 5 pages from my Google Analytics Project API in PHP. So far I've made the following code, but it doesn't appear to work - any ideas?

```
 private function getTopPages($profileId) {

   $optParams = array(
      'sort' => 'ga:pageviews',
      'max-results' => '5');

   return $this->analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       '2012-09-01',
       '2012-09-30',
       'ga:pagePath',
       $optParams);

}
```

Comment: `it doesn't appear to work` , can you be a little more specific? What's the output? What's the server's response?

Comment: it doesn't return anything, no error, not even a null. Very confused, I've tried var_dump, die - to try and get something from it

Comment: The code in my answer works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 private function getTopPages($profileId) {

        $optParams = array(
            'max-results' => 5,
            'dimensions' => 'ga:pageTitle,ga:pagePath',
            'sort' => '-ga:pageviews',
        );

   return $this->analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       '2012-09-01',
       '2012-09-30',
       'ga:pageviews',
       $optParams);

}
```

inspired by: http://axiacore.com/blog/how-get-list-most-popular-pages-google-analytics-python/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specifics of the php calls, but I see the following potential problems with your call:

- You would need to specify the sort as **descending**.  It is probably ascending by default.
- You need to specify somewhere your metric as **ga:pageviews**.  While you have this in your sort option, you also need to specify it for the metric.  Is this the **ga:** parameter?

I have found  [GA Explorer Tool](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/) to be of help.